# How to convert survey answers in data frame to numbers in order to average results

Tags: r

I have a data frame with survey results that looks like this:

```
          Q1         Q2       Q3
1      Agree No opinion Disagree
2 No opinion No opinion Disagree
3      Agree            Disagree
```

How can I convert the survey responses into numbers so that I can get the mean response for each question? I can use gsub to substitute numeric values for each text answer in each column, but there must be a better way.

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Q1: Factor w/ 2 levels "Agree","No opinion": 1 2 1
 $ Q2: Factor w/ 2 levels "","No opinion": 2 2 1
 $ Q3: Factor w/ 1 level "Disagree": 1 1 1
```

Comment: How 'bout `sapply(data, as.integer)` ?

Comment: @TheodoreLytras That assumes a lot about the structure of their data. Factor vs character, and even if they are factors, we don't know the order of the levels.

Comment: @Theodore data.matrix(data) gives the same results, but doesn't make consistent conversions across columns.

Comment: @joran Indeed. That's why I didn't post it as an answer, because it is a hint to the OP that more info is needed.

Comment: @outis why not to use `table` here?

Comment: @Theodore I don't know enough to interpret the hint, unfortunately. I can read the data as factors, and say Agree > No opinion > Disagree. What other info can I provide?

Comment: @agstudy Because apparently they think that if I Agree with something and you Disagree, as a group we have No Opinion. ;)

Comment: Share your data via `dput(head())` or show us the output of `str()`.

Comment: @joran +1! well well! classy:)

Comment: What do you mean by *mean response*? If it is not numeric data, averaging a dummy variable is not the way to go. If you mean you would like to report the proportion of people reporting a particular response to a question then you don't need to convert to numeric, you can just use factor variables

Comment: I added the output of str() to the question. This is just a small example that looks like the actual data.

Comment: I agree with @agstudy. Given the structure of your data, just use `table(x)` surely?

Comment: agstudy, @SimonO101 I see, you mean a table for each column of answers. That's probably the answer to the question I should have asked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877065/set-ordering-of-factor-levels-for-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, it is clear now.

I would convert each column to character, then to factor (with common levels), then to integer:

```
sapply(data, function(x) as.integer(factor(as.character(x), levels=c("Agree", "No opinion", "Disagree"))))
```

Comment: alternatively, use an *ordered factor*

Answer (score 0):

I must be misunderstanding what you want, but since you have categorical variables in a `data.frame` can't you just use `summary` on it?

```
#Example
q1 <- sample( c("Agree" , "No opinion" ) , 10 , replace = TRUE )
q2 <- sample( c(" " , "No opinion" ) , 10 , replace = TRUE )
q3 <- sample( c("Agree" , "Disagree" ) , 10 , replace = TRUE )

x <- data.frame( q1 , q2 , q3 )

summary(x)
  q1             q2           q3   
  Agree     :4   ,         :4   Agree   :5  
  No opinion:6   No opinion:6   Disagree:5
```